# Django: loosing form attribute when changing <select> options in form template

Tags: jquery, django, forms

In my Django application, a template which displays the manually the form fields from a Model. In this template I have a few fields which are  and the options are set in my `forms.py`. One of the option is a tuple `('new','New...')` and when it is selected a pop up windows appears (Bootstrap Modal) and the user can add an option which is added to the choices of the `select`.

But when the form is submited, I have an error as the form key for this field is missing: `KeyError: 'country'`, and if I print the form, country key is absent:

```
{'genotype': '?', 'complete_genome': False, 'seq_tech': '?', 'isolation_source': 'te', 'mol_type': '?', 'NT_seq': 'TTG', 'source': '?', 'host': 'chicken', 'species': 'A', 'isolate': 'te1', 'sourceLink': '', 'subtyping_ref': '?', 'PK_idSequence': 'test', 'strain': 'te1_strain', 'comment': '', 'subtype': '?'}
```

My `forms.py`:

```
UNKNOWN_START_LIST = [('?','?')]
NEW_END_LIST = [('new','New...')]

class SequenceForm(ModelForm):

    # create the form fields
    PK_idSequence = CharField(max_length=15, label='Sequence ID')

    # get the existing country values in the database
    tmpCountries = sorted(list(set([seq.country for seq in Sequence.objects.all() if seq.country is not None and seq.country != '?'])))
    countryChoices = UNKNOWN_START_LIST + [(tmpCountry, tmpCountry) for tmpCountry in tmpCountries] + NEW_END_LIST

    # the countryChoices will be [('?', '?'), ('France', 'France'), ('Germany', 'Germany'), ('Japan', 'Japan'), ('USA', 'USA'), ('new', 'New...')]
    country = ChoiceField(choices = countryChoices,
                    initial='?', 
                    required = False)

    # ... more stuffs


    class Meta:
        model = Sequence
        fields = ['PK_idSequence', 'genotype', 'subtype', 'host', 'country', 'complete_genome', 'seq_tech', 'NT_seq', 'col_date',
                'isolation_source', 'isolate', 'strain', 'species', 'mol_type', 'subtyping_ref', 'source', 'sourceLink', 'comment']

    # custom clean form for Sequence    
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(SequenceForm, self).clean()

        # where the error is raised
        if cleaned_data['country'] is not None:
            cleaned_data['country'] = cleaned_data.get('country').title()
```

my `template.html`:

```
{# The modal window to record a new Country #}
<div id="modal_new_country" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Record a new country:</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="text" name="new_country_text" id="new_country_text">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button id="new_country_button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    <button id="new_country_cancel_button" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<form class="single_upload_form" action="{% url 'upload' dataType method %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="{{form.name.css_classes}}">
                {{form.PK_idSequence.label_tag}}{{ form.PK_idSequence.errors }}</br><span class="form_field">{{ form.PK_idSequence }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="{{form.name.css_classes}}">
                {{ form.country.label_tag }}{{ form.country.errors }}</br><span class="form_field">{{ form.country }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

my `jQuery.js`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
/* ############### Country dropdown select ############### */

    // in upload form if Country dropdown is set to New... create a modal to get the new country
    $("#id_country").change(function(){
        var selectedValue = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("value");
        switch (selectedValue){
            case "new":
                $('#modal_new_country').modal('show');
                break;
        }
    }); 

    // Add the new Country to the select options
    $("#new_country_button").click(function() {
        var newCountry = $("#new_country_text").val();
        newCountry = newCountry.substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + newCountry.substr(1);
        $('#id_country').append('<option value="'+newCountry+'" selected="selected">'+newCountry+'</option>');
        $('#modal_new_country').modal('hide');
    });

    // cancel button for modal Country set selected option to '?'
    $("#new_country_cancel_button").click(function() {
        $('#id_country').val('?');
        $('#modal_new_country').modal('hide');
    });

})
```

I guess the problem comes from that the new value in the `select` `id_country` is not part of the initial options coming from the `form`, how could I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it can help, I found a way to add a new `<option>` to the `<select> #id_country`. In my `forms.py` I replaced the `ChoiceField` by a `CharField` which widget is a `forms.Select` where I put the `countryChoices`:

```
country = ChoiceField(choices = countryChoices, initial='?', required = False)
```

by

```
country = CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.Select(choices=countryChoices), required=False)
```

So, as the country attribute is a `CharField`, there is no more validation error raised by `invalid_choice` and the `form cleaned_data` has now the new value for the key `'country'`.